# Visual Studio : Windows 10 Emulator not starting

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, windows-10-mobile, windows-phone-emulator

I am developing a UWP application on my Windows 10 machine and whenever I try to run the emulator, it pops up the below error. I have a Core i5 6th Gen CPU and 8GB RAM as my standard setup.

It is not even allowing 512 MB RAM's emulator as well.

[image]

Comment: I would suggest trying to go to Hyper-V Manager to see if you can launch the emulator VM from there. Also it would definitely be worth upgrading to VS 2017 as there has been a number of improvements since 2015.

Comment: 10586 is out of support, only Build 15254 gets updates until end of this year when they kill Win10 mobile at all. so try the [15254 Emulator](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=615095)

Comment: @MartinZikmund It is not letting me run it. I get some exception when I try running the emulator from the Hyper V Application

Comment: That means there is something wrong with the emulator image itself. Maybe try uninstalling and reinstalling it

Comment: @magicandre1981 Installed the recommended version but now it gives RAM issues though I have 8GB of RAM

Comment: please post an image of the new error message. Also which windows 10 version/build do you use?

Comment: any update on the issue?

Comment: No. I downloaded even the latest emulators but the fix is not helping

Comment: try this: https://bstar.de/2016/09/04/visual-studio-and-windows-10-emulator/

Comment: have you tried the step from my last link I've posted?

Comment: I will do in the due course and update you.Please give me sometime. My current system doesnt have VS